# String replace not work with if statement

Tags: string, integer

1.I have an issue with String not replacing in this code
2.I tried to practice make a Clock and try to make seconds shown as "00"

````
       SeekBar timerSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.timerSeekBar);

        TextView timerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerTextView);

        timerSeekBar.setMax(600);
        timerSeekBar.setProgress(30);


                int minutes = (int) progress/60;
                int seconds =  progress-minutes * 60;

                String secondString = Integer.toString(seconds);
//he is the problem it not pass right string .
                if (secondString =="0"){

                    secondString = "00";

                }

                timerTextView.setText(Integer.toString(minutes)+ ":"+secondString);

                Log.i("check String", secondString);


    }```
````

Comment: Use String formatting to format the string to desire formats. Like String.format("%d", 101) or String.format("My answer is %15.8f", 47.65734)

Comment: thanks. but it not work on this. this code seems right. but it doesn't output right

Comment: What value does progress represents? Is it in hours?